# Eliminating the need for packages in base R?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization

I know one of the reasons R is so popular is because of its amazing packages. But for data security reasons, I can't install packages on my work computer. So, it got me thinking if I could still make R do what I would typically make it do using packages with just base R, since packages are, after all, a compiled list of functions. I am wondering if it is possible run regression models and make charts in base R (without using, say `ggplot2`, `caret`, etc.). Is it possible to copy the functions in these packages into base R to get the same functionality out of base R as one would if they were using the packages? Is the list of functions that are published as part of these packages available somewhere publicly by chance?

Comment: One potential solution: You can keep your package library on an external drive, and just tell R to look there for packages.  You may also be able to install R with its package library on an external drive, if you have permission to execute a program on an external drive.

Comment: R is open source and the packages you mention are contributed packages, meaning, they are on the official, public repository [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/). You can download the source code of all of them, see [Available CRAN Packages By Name](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html). But this would mean that you would become responsible for their maintenance.

Comment: All packages on CRAN are available [on this Github CRAN mirror](https://github.com/cran) (and many packages are developed on Github and have their actual homepages there). Package authors generally try not to include extraneous code, so while you can look in a packages NAMESPACE file to see what functions are *exported* to be readily available to users, you should generally assume that all the code included in packages is needed for them to function fully.

Comment: With some simple packages you may be able to just copy the function definitions and run them, but if you look at, e.g., [ggplot2's description file](https://github.com/cran/ggplot2/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L28) it relies on code from 13 other packages and "Suggests" (meaning it could potentially use code from) quite a few other packages. And those packages have their own dependencies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is possible run regression models and make charts in base R (without using, say ggplot2, caret, etc.).

Yes, before `ggplot2` was invented, R was genereally praised for publication ready graphics. R comes with great plotting capabilities without `ggplot2` even though the latter is definitively an improvement.
Obviously, people used R for regression decades before `caret` was invented. A base R installation comes with a solid set of linear and nonlinear regression methods but obviously, all those packages (well, most of them) have a reason to exist. It will mainly depend on what you plan to do use. Many things are implemented in a base  installation, many are not.

You can find lists of packages included with all binary distributions of R here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-FAQ.html#Add_002don-packages-in-R
You will find, that that not only includes the `stats` package but lots of useful modelling packages like `MASS`, `splines`, `boot`, `mgcv`, `nlme`, `cluster`, `rpart`, `spatial` and `survival`, so a large number of even specialized models is at hand without additional downloading of packages.

> Is it possible to copy the functions in these packages into base R to get the same functionality out of base R as one would if they were using the packages?

Many packages contain just plain R code, others will contain code in other languages, mostly C and C++, which will need a compiler to be translated on your system. However, where the use of foreign code / packages is considered a security breach, you should refrain from that and talk to your employer.

If it is not considered a problem but they do not want to make exceptions for you and your installation -- I was in the same place for quite some time and I just ran R from a USB stick. If that is allowed and feasible on your system, you can download packages to that USB stick installation.